# How do you change an iOS app's filename on the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to alter the filename of an app. I am not talking about the product name which is displayed under the icon on the home screen, I am talking about the actual filename on the device's storage.

Is there a way to alter this? I am using XCode 4.4.

Comment: In your target. Go to Build Settings. Change Product Name present inside Packaging. Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: There was an answer here a bit ago that (I think) solved my problem... don't know why it was deleted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Xcode -> Project -> Build Settings -> Packaging`, change **Product Name**. Note that doing this will cause another instance of your application to be installed if people have already downloaded your old version. This method changes your bundle so the phone thinks your new version is a new app.

You can keep the same bundle ID by changing your `Info.plist` file to not use `${PRODUCT_NAME}` and manually set it to your old `PRODUCT_NAME`

Comment: Another instance? If you mean another app gets installed with the same name then you are incorrect. The app is tied to a bundle Id. So as long as the app has the same bundle id then only one instance is present in your phone. Could you clarify what you meant?

Comment: @S.P. This changes your bundle. So yes, there would be another instance. I have edited my answer to add an alternative

Comment: I have tried this multiple times. There never was another instance. Instead the old app gets re written. Try it and you will be able to see it.

Comment: @S.P. I tried this myself and it gave me another instance of the app.

Comment: Well, I don't know but Apple's documentation as well as my experiences differ from what you are experiencing. If I keep the same bundle Id and change the App name only. My old app gets removed and the new app gets written on top of it.

Comment: yes, you can force the bundle id manually, I have my bundle ID being set as the ${PRODUCT_NAME}

Comment: Yes, that must be it! Thanks for the discussion though.

Answer (score 0):

If you double tap your project name, it should change your application filename. 
You should definitely backup your project before you do this, just incase anything goes wrong.

Here's an example:
[image]

Comment: I don't want to change the project name. Only the filename.

Comment: This will change your filename too. This will become Blah.app